# How to view error logs for Azure Bot Service that uses a Messaging endpoint

Tags: azure, logging, monitoring, azure-bot-service

I've configured a Bot Service on Azure that uses a Messaging endpoint. This messaging endpoint corresponds to an API that is hosted by another cloud provider and is where the bot code is deployed. Within the Teams app, where the bot is used, I'm seeing 500-level errors when communication is attempted with the Azure bot APIs (
https://teams.microsoft.com/api/chatsvc/*). I'm trying to determine where these errors are occurring and more information about them.

I have logging set up on the cloud provider that the bot code is hosted on, and I'm not seeing errors, making me think that failure is occurring before reaching it. I was instructed to set up a Diagnostic setting within the Bot Service and associated it with a Log Analytics workspace, but when I try to search and analyze the logs using Log Analytics, nothing is returned.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!